How to spontaneously swap numerous iterations of two different strings with Notepad++?
I have a .txt file that I need to edit by swapping out two strings:
XENON_A
XENON_Y

I need to replace all iterations of the string XENON_A with XENON_Y, and all iterations of the string XENON_Y with XENON_A all in one go. How can I accomplish this with Notepad ++ ?
I have looked at this question, but it doesn't seem to fit.
This article on the Notepad++ talks about swapping, but only for what is in the Replace field.

Try the following:

Press Ctrl+H to open the Replace window
Find what box, type: XENON_\K(?:(A)|(Y))
Replace with: (?1Y)(?2A)
Search mode: Regular expression

Before

After


@Toto thanks for the advice.
